# error C2062: type 'void' unexpected in signal declaration in QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, signals

I am a newbie, I am writing a header file in which I am declaring a class which will emit a signal. So I declare my class with a constructor, two `int` variables which I make `private`, and then I define my `signal`. Here is my `.h` file:

```
#ifndef KEYBOARD_H
#define KEYBOARD_H

class KeyBoard{
public:
    KeyBoard();
    int keyboard_update();
private:
    int level;
    int sub_level;
signals:
    void send_to_MBU(QString message);
};

#endif
```

Now In `.cpp` part, I am just emitting a signal in the constructor.Here is the code in `.cpp` part:

```
#include "KeyBoard.h"

KeyBoard::KeyBoard()
{
    level = 0;
    sub_level = 0;
    emit send_to_MBU("PRESS ENTER TO SELECT TRAIN"): 
}

int KeyBoard::keyboard_update()
{
    return 1;
}
```

But when I am compiling my code, I am getting this error in my signal declaration:

```
error C2062: type 'void' unexpected
```

For me, the code looks fine. But as am newbie. I can't figure out the issue. So, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You may be missing a header that performs the magic that allows `signals:` to function.

Comment: Here we go. [From QT Documentation:](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) "All classes that contain signals or slots must mention `Q_OBJECT` at the top of their declaration. They must also derive (directly or indirectly) from `QObject`"

Comment: @user4581301 : Thanks, I was missing #include <QObject> to declare. It's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to declare `#include <QObject>` in `.h` file to successfully using signals in QT. That's the only thing missing in header file. new code looks like this:-

```
#ifndef KEYBOARD_H
#define KEYBOARD_H

#include <QObject>

class KeyBoard : QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    KeyBoard();
    int keyboard_update(char* recieved_key);
private:
    int level;
    int sub_level;
signals:
    void send_to_MBU(QString message);
};

#endif
```